# PHP Excel Exporting drops leading Zeros

Tags: php, excel

I have a script to export the contents of a MySQL database which works fine apart from on a column which has leading zeros. For some reason these get dropped.

Is there a way I could modify the code to retain those leading zeros?

Many thanks!

```html
$sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName";
$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
//select database   
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());   
//execute query 
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    
$file_ending = "xls";
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
}
print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $schema_insert = "";
        for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
        {
            if(!isset($row[$j]))
                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
            elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            else
                $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
        }
        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert .= "\t";
        print(trim($schema_insert));
        print "\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to preserve the leading zeros, Excel must treat the data as text (or some custom number format like "00000000").

I found a potential solution from [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/318420/formatting-a-comma-delimited-csv-to-force-excel-to-interpret-value-as-a-string). Basically, data in the following format will be treated as text because the value will be encapsulated by double quotes: "=""00123"""

I think your code would change to:

```
[snip]
      elseif ($row[$j] != "")
            $schema_insert .= '"=""$row[$j]"""'.$sep;
[snip]
```

Or whatever would generate the necessary quotes shown in the sample.